# The passive voice of ''apply''

Tags: passive-voice

Can this sentence "I have applied for samples that you requested." be replaced by this sentence"Samples that you requested have been applied"?

As far as I know, when the word "apply" means "ask", its part of speech is intransitive.But I have seen some sentences that use "apply" as passive voice. So it's quite confusing to me.

Comment: There are lots of different meanings of *apply*. The passive tends to be for the transitive meaning. Look in a [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apply).

Comment: Agree ^^. In this context you'd say "The samples that you requested have been applied for"

Comment: The natural reading of your “... have been applied” version is that the samples have been *used*.

Comment: No wonder they always call me back when I mail that message to them...

Comment: No, it can’t. *I have applied for samples that you requested* lacks, at least, an article, as in *I have applied for the samples…*
*Samples that you requested have been applied* is worse and means nothing like the correct form, *… have been applied for*.
Part of the problem is that *apply* never means *ask*.
To *apply* and to *apply for* share nothing.
We *apply* rules or bandages, various chemicals; perhaps even ourselves.
We *apply for* passports, permission, positions, visas and the like.
There is no comparison.

Comment: I think "The samples that you requested have been ordered" or "The samples that you requested are on order" might remove some ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your confusion is that the verb applied is indeed intransitive, but this is a phrasal verb that is actually being used here.  This is indeed correct below.

> Samples that you requested have been applied **FOR**.

What is happening is that this is the phrasal verb-

> Apply for

Not

> Apply

Please refer to this entry in the [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/apply+for) about this phrasal verb.

A preposition at the end of a sentence in this example is correct because *for* is a particle of the verb phrase...

Answer (score -6):

Passive words for the apply are as follows:

Implement
Use
Infuse
Impose

Comment: Sorry, Zincha. It's true some of your words sometimes share meanings with *apply* but have you actually tried substituting and of them?

*Samples that you requested have been implemented/used/infused/imposed* would generally be worse than *applied*.